# How can I dynamically update the class in my shortcode?

Tags: php, shortcode

I made a heading shortcode

**Here it is:**

```
function heading( $atts, $content = null ) {
    // [head][/head]
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(), $atts, 'head' );

    // do shortcode actions here
    $output = "<h1 class=\"banner-heading update-\">".$content."</h1>";
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'head','heading' );
```

**What I want:**

I want to increment my update class dynamically when ever I write the shortcode in the editor. Something like this update-0, update-1 etc.

**UPDATED:**

```
function heading( $atts, $content = null ) {
    // [head][/head]
    static $instance = 0;
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(), $atts, 'head' );

    // do shortcode actions here
    $output = "<h1 class=\"banner-heading update-."$instance"\">".$content."</h1>";
    $instance++;
    return $output;

}
add_shortcode( 'head','heading' );
```

Comment: Off topic: For SEO it is usually advised to only have one `<h1>` per entire page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if this is the nth instance of a given shortcode in a post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59945/how-to-check-if-this-is-the-nth-instance-of-a-given-shortcode-in-a-post)

Comment: @kero, not really. Matt Cutts on [More than one H1 on a page: good or bad?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIn5qJKU8VM).

Comment: @OwaizYusufi would be nice if you could post the solution an an answer to your own question, instead of as an update of the question.